# What are the properties of a WebGLUniformLocation object?

Tags: javascript, webgl

This is my fragment shader, that contains a `uniform`:

```
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D uSampler;
varying vec2 vPosition;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vPosition);
}
```

Now where I call the function `getUniformLocation`:

```
var uniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uSampler')
```

I get a `WebGLUniformLocation` with seemingly no properties attached to it:

```
for(a in uniformLocation) { console.log(a); } // prints no results
```

Why is the `WebGLUniformLocation` object propertyless?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `WebGLUniformLocation` is just an opaque handle to the location of a uniform so that you can set the uniform. In real OpenGL uniform locations are integers. Unfortunately many programmers will do math on those integers. For example they might do something like this

```
//--shader--
uniform float a;
uniform float b;
...

// C
GLint location_a = glGetUniformLocation(program, "a");
GLint location_b = a + 1;   // ILLEGAL BUT MIGHT WORK ON SOME CARDS
```

Similarly they might do this

```
//--shader--
uniform float a[2];
...

// C
GLint location_a0 = glGetUniformLocation(program, "a[0]");
GLint location_a1 = a + 1;   // ILLEGAL BUT MIGHT WORK ON SOME CARDS
```

Or they could do this

```
//--shader #1--
uniform float a;
...

//--shader #2--
uniform float a;
...


// C
GLint program_1 = CompileShadersAndLinkProgram(shader_1_src, ..);
GLint program_2 = CompileShadersAndLinkProgram(shader_2_src, ..);

// Get the location from program 1
GLint location_a = glGetUniformLocation(program_1, "a");

// Use a location from program 1 with program 2
glUseProgram(program_2);
glUnform1f(location_a, 123);  // ILLEGAL BUT MIGHT WORK ON SOME CARDS
```

All of these are illegal and wrong according to the OpenGL spec. Sometimes that's ok. If you're writing some OpenGL program and you only need it to work on your personal machine or some fixed hardware then you probably don't care if it's wrong if it happens to work.

For WebGL though that's not good enough. You'd like, where possible, to write the code once and have it run everywhere. In order to prevent those kinds of errors WebGL returns a `WebGLUniformLocation` so that you can't do any math and you can't use one program's locations on another program.

Comment: Very helpful. I thought I was getting erroneous results for my location values until I read this